# python transfer art cartoon with custom dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, transfer-learning

How can I cartoonize images with the model trained with a custom dataset? There are projects on the internet that cartoonize pictures with library methods without a dataset, but I couldn't find a project source for the purpose I wanted. Could you post resources that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using neural style transfer with PyTorch, use the style image as the cartoon image and the content image as the image that you wish to cartoonize.

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/neural_style_tutorial.html